# SSRS Report to execute another as a main report without passing parameters

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

The requirement is to effectively have an initial CheckAccess report, which identifies the currently logged in Windows user and checking this value against a list of report Id + user to see if they have access.

I have written the initial CheckAccess report and setup 2 parameters within it. The first is a report ID and the second is the User, which is calculated from the SSRS UserID field. I am checking a database table for a match for both, which identifies the user can run the report.

If no entry is found I am displaying a banner on the CheckAccess report accordingly i.e. You are not allowed access to this report.

If an entry is found I would like to automatically run another report. I want to run this 'called' report as if the user had run it directly. It has a number of parameters but I don't want to have to define these in this CheckAccess report.

I've tried setting the called report as a subreport, but this requires me to setup the parameters.

Is there anyway I can run this report directly from the CheckAccess report?

I have tinkered with a separate text box, which has an Action to run the called report, which works but requires the user to click the textbox. Ideally this would be what I'm after but to automatically trigger the action.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it as you really want but 2 alternatives. 1. Setup security in SSRS directly, the users just won't see reports they have no access to. 2. Assming you have some reason not to use SSRS security, you could have report that lists all the reports they do have access to, with a link to each report.

Comment: Thanks Alan but both options are not practical for my requirement. The report is already part of the standard menu which is available to all users. A super user will have access to the specific report controls and decide which reports the users can access hence my having to control it in this manner. I don;t want to get into having the IT department manage operational accesses via the SSRS security setup. These generic menus are available to several users and only specific reports within the menu need to be controlled via this additional level of security.

Comment: The only alternative would be to have my original definition whereby if they are allowed access, the 'Not allowed access' message is hidden and I display another textbox with something like 'Click to run' with the Action pointing to the desired report. This does work as I've tested it but each time the user would have to select this. It's a bit clunky.

Comment: Thanks again Alan for giving it some thought.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of (again not nice) Is to set default parameters on each report just so it executes even if it returns nothing and then have an overlapping textbox control with visibility controlled by whether the user has access or not. The textbox would cover the empty report controls.

Comment: Currently, the report has this as I set a Report variable determined whether the LOOKUP using the Report ID + Username exists in my Database Table. I hide the report if no entry exists and display the 'Not allowed access' otherwise vice versa. The downside of this is the user has to enter valid parameters to then be greeted with the message.

Comment: If you set default parameters on the report as I mentioned , if will execute first time with no user input. The user can then change the parameters when they actually want to use it in earnest.